# `require': can't modify frozen SystemStackError (FrozenError) :: Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Al ejecutar mi app que cloné desde Heroku, me marca lo siguiente:

```
C:\Sites\salty-depths-42099>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require': can't modify frozen SystemStackError (FrozenError)
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
Rails 4.2.4
jruby 9.2.0.0 (2.5.0) 2018-05-24 81156a8 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13 on 1.8.0_181-b13 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]
gem -v 2.7.7
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda faltarme?, ya borre el `gemfile.lock` para que se vuelva a generar y nada, agregue a mi *gemfile* **gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"** y corrí `bundle install`

Comment: Una razón que la aplicación te funcione en heroku (porque asumo que eso quieres decir con que la clonaste desde ahí) y no en tu máquina puede ser porque tu estás usando windows. Heroku funciona con máquinas que usan linux. Pero con la información que entregas no es suficiente para saber que pueda ser. Tampoco hay muchas referencias en internet relacionado con ese error, pero "creo" que puedes estar haciendo algún loop infinito en alguna parte de tu código que te arroje el `SystemStackError`, aunque claro, eso no tiene relación con el cambio de O.S. ¿estás seguro que te funciona en heroku?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, si la corro desde heroku la app funciona, creare una maquina virtual

Comment: Parece ser algún error por incompatibilidad entre la versión 2.5 de ruby y alguna de las gemas; ¿estás utilizando la misma versión de Ruby que la que está en Heroku? Prueba utilizando una versión anterior (i.e. 2.4.x).

Comment: Gracias me funciono con la versión 2.3.3